# Kotlin - convert map result to typed arraylist

Tags: android, loops, dictionary, kotlin, arraylist

I am having a hard time converting the result of map in to its model type

```
 val options = message.options.map {{
        it.lastShare = user?.lastShare
        it.lastWatch = user?.lastWatch
    }}
```

I want the options to return as type `ArrayList<Option>` but I can't find anything on the internet. The `message.options` is of type List. when I do `.map` it returns `List<() -> Unit>`.

Comment: what type is `options`?

Comment: options is just a data class @Sergey

Comment: do you have any errors? Please remove one pair of braces in your code and see if it works

Comment: @Sergey ofcourse because I cant pass it to the function that acceps `ArrayList<Option>`

Comment: can you change the type of  function parameter to `List<Option>`?

Answer (score 3):

Please try next code:

```
val options = message.options.map {
    it.lastShare = user?.lastShare
    it.lastWatch = user?.lastWatch
    it
}
```

or in your case I think you don't need to use `map` function, you can simply use `forEach` to update properties of each object in the list:

```
message.options.forEach {
    it.lastShare = user?.lastShare
    it.lastWatch = user?.lastWatch
}

val optionsArrayList: ArrayList<Option> = arrayListOf(*message.options.toTypedArray())
```

`*` - is a [**spread**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) operator.

Or simpler way to create an `ArrayList` is just use its constructor:

```
val optionsArrayList: ArrayList<Option> = ArrayList(message.options)
```

Comment: just `val optionsArrayList = ArrayList(message.options)`

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
val options = message.options.map {{
    it.lastShare = user?.lastShare
    it.lastWatch = user?.lastWatch
}}.toMutableList()
```